# Python telegram bot Filters

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've been making a bot and I used `filters=Filters.private`for start_command then i used it in a `MessageHandler` and it is the code:
dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command, filters=Filters.private))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.private, start_keyboard_answers))

it works perfectly but the problem is that i need to make another filter inside of second one and the code supposed to be like that:

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command, filters=Filters.private))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.private, start_keyboard_answers, filters=Filters.private))
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.private, start_keyboard_answers))

but it's impossible and i have two filters in second line
how can i handle this?
i will put full project down here if u wanna know what I'm realy doing(im looking for other buttons after second keyboard just like what I did to first and second one):

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, Filters, CommandHandler, MessageHandler
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup

BOT_TOKEN = ''

def start_command(update, context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text='Hey, welcome to Chocolate Coffee!'
    )
    keyboard = [
        ['Make an Order']
    ]
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=chat_id,
        text='How can I help you?',
        reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True)
    )

def start_keyboard_answers(update, context):
    message_text = str(update.message.text)
    if message_text.lower() == 'make an order':
        update.message.reply_text(
            text='Okay :)',
            quote=True
        )
        keyboard = [
            ['breakfast'],
            ['coffee'],
            ['milkshake'],
            ['colddrink'],
            ['food'],
            ['mocktail'],
            ['icecream'],
            ['organic'],
            ['smoothi'],
            ['glossy'],
            ['tea']
        ]
        chat_id = update.message.chat.id
        context.bot.sendMessage(chat_id,"ok, then?",reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True, resize_keyboard=True))
        
        message_text = str(update.message.text)
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        if message_text.lower() == 'breakfast':
            update.message.reply_text(
                text='Okay :)',
                quote=True
            )
def main():
    updater = Updater(token=BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start_command, filters=Filters.private))
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.private, start_keyboard_answers))

    updater.start_polling()
    print('Started!')
    updater.idle()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument to the `MessageHandler` is `filters`

We can chain multiple filters with bitwise operators( `&` - AND, `|` - OR, `~` - NOT) and pass it as first argument. Like this,

```
MessageHandler(filters = Filters.private & Filters.chat([ADMINS ID here]), callbacks = who_do_you_wanna_call_here)
```

or simply

```
MessageHandler(Filters.private & Filters.command, start_cmd_ck)
```

Although from the code, I could see you would need a `ConversationHandler` to arrange a step-by-step conversation with the users. Check out this [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py) here